# What language/framework for gamification system?

Tags: php, jquery, api, design-patterns, frameworks

I'm gonna develope a really simple gamification system (only credits, badges and levels at the beginning) for an existing website but I really don't know how to start. Can you suggest me if there are APIs or Frameworks or something else to start this development process. The website is developed in PHP and jQuery.

I neither know how to start. I really would apprecciate links, tutorials, books or anything else to introduce myself in gamification developing. Do I need a special DB structure or special design patterns or architectural patterns?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gamification? Do we traffic in marketing-speak on SO now?

Comment: Come on...you know what I mean. Gamification: achievements, badges, levels, etc. It's just easier using one word to indicate all these elements.

Comment: Before the social engineers got in on it, we just used the words achievements, incentives, or competition - I'm not convinced gamification brings anything to the table semantically.

Comment: So because some lingo was used you don't agree with you simply close the topic? Get over yourselves.

Comment: @cosmicbdog I voted to close because it's just way too broad of a question - the exact words used didn't influence me in voting to close. You should be careful when making assumptions about other people's motivations. Often times we don't even understand ourselves that well, let alone other people.

Comment: @jball fair enough. thanks for the advice - i will be more careful in the future

Comment: Just arrived from google and would have loved an answer for this, I don't see why this was not a real question. @jball it doesn't bring anything "semantically"? Besides not having to call it "achievements, incentives, or competition"? I suppose its easier to call it these 3 phrases as well as multiple others? Totally agree with cosmicbdog here.

Comment: Also came here from Google.  By searching for Gamification.  Because that's what it's called.

"Back in my day, we didn't need a word for tablets.  We just called them computers without a keyboard!"

Comment: @SSHThis and Scott Beeson, you've both missed the point of my first two comments, and also conflated my first two comments with the reason the question was closed. Read my third comment for more on the reason I voted to close. As for the point of my first comment, let me spell it out more precisely. "Gamification" is simply a rebranding of any number of terms which can be used singly to describe the same thing. Rewards, or incentives, or goals, or contests - pick your poison. What is it that "gamification" says that any one of those terms does not?

Comment: Also, @ScottBeeson, you're welcome to keep your fallacious straw man example to yourself. You won't see me contesting the addition of "tablet" to the technological lexicon.

Comment: I agree that this question is valid. I understand that it is broad question, but I understand it and quite frankly would like to know if there are any answers to this question myself.